# System-level and segment-level correlation

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, natural-language

In a few NLP papers such as [Re-evaluating Evaluation in Text Summarization](https://aclanthology.org/2020.emnlp-main.751) (Bhandari et al., EMNLP 2020), two types of correlation strategies are presented. I had a discussion with colleagues over the rationale behind those correlation types and we were unable to arrive at a consensus.

**Setup**: For each document $d_i$, $i \in \{1, \dots, N\}$ in a dataset, we have $J$ system outputs. Let $y_i^j$, $j \in \{1, \dots, J\}$ be the $j$-th output of the $i$-th document, $m_1$ and $m_2$ be two evaluation metrics and $K$ a correlation measure (such as Pearson's $r$).

The segment-level correlation is defined as:
$$K^\textrm{segment}_{m_1, m_2} =
     \frac{1}{N}
     \sum_{i=1}^N
     K     
                    \left(
     \begin{bmatrix}
     m_1(y_{i}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{i}^J) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     ,
     \begin{bmatrix}
     m_2(y_{i}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{i}^J) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     \right)
     $$

and the system-level correlation as:

$$K^\textrm{system}_{m_1, m_2} =
     K     
                    \left(
     \frac{1}{N}
     \sum_{i=1}^N
\begin{bmatrix}
     m_1(y_{i}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{i}^J) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     ,
\frac{1}{N}
     \sum_{i=1}^N
     \begin{bmatrix}
     m_2(y_{i}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{i}^J) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     \right)
     $$

In particular, we were unsure about the segment-level correlation: why do we average over correlations instead of concatenating all vectors for all documents such as:

$$K^\textrm{segment}_{m_1, m_2} =
     K     
                    \left(
     \begin{bmatrix}
     m_1(y_{1}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{1}^J) \\
     m_1(y_{2}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{2}^J) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{n}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{n}^J) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     ,
     \begin{bmatrix}
     m_2(y_{1}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{1}^J) \\
     m_2(y_{2}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{2}^J) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{n}^1) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{n}^J) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     \right)
     $$

Or why don't we average over the $J$ axis rather than the $n$ axis such as:
$$K^\textrm{system}_{m_1, m_2} =
     K     
                    \left(
     \frac{1}{J}
     \sum_{j=1}^J
\begin{bmatrix}
     m_1(y_{1}^j) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_1(y_{N}^j) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     ,
\frac{1}{J}
     \sum_{j=1}^J
     \begin{bmatrix}
     m_2(y_{1}^j) \\
     \vdots \\
     m_2(y_{N}^j) \\
     \end{bmatrix}
     \right)
     $$

Finally, what could be the practical significance and usage of those correlation types?

Comment: Have you asked the authors of the paper? They are the best people to answer this question.

Comment: Good point, I've just done that.